# What is the most similar distro/flavor to the original UNIX source code?

Tags: kernel, source-code, historical-unix

Just like Ubuntu, Arch, Red Hat etc are just modifications to the [original Linux Kernel](https://www.kernel.org)... macOS (XNU), Solaris etc are some variants of the closed source code of AT&T's UNIX. But what is the purest UNIX kernel or distribution, per se?

Is the UNIX kernel code (the original one) completely lost? Or is it still being maintained by someone (AT&T)?

If there is an up-to-date nothing-except-the-kernel-source-code? How can I get my hands on it? (I obviously intend to pay) Is it available under personal/student license or do I need to buy a business license?

P.S. I have a limited knowledge about UNIX.

Comment: One of the BSD releases perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD is likely the most directly-derived modern UNIX-based OS.  In June of 2017, Diomidis
Spinellis of the Athens University of Economics and Business
[published a research paper](https://www2.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/jrnl/2016-EMPSE-unix-history/html/unix-history.pdf) which documents the evolution of the Bell Labs UNIX codebase from its early beginnings through to the modern-day FreeBSD 12.  Using a variety of sources and methods, he essentially reconstructed a Git repository timeline which traces current-day FreeBSD back to epochal origin of UNIX.

> The project has achieved its major goal with the establishment of a
>   continuous timeline from 1970 until today. The repository contains:
>
> - snapshots of PDP-7, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, and V7 Research Edition,
> - Unix/32V,
> - all available BSD releases,
> - the CSRG SCCS history,
> - two releases of 386BSD,
> - the 386BSD patchkit,
> - the FreeBSD 1.0 to 1.1.5 CVS history,
> - an import of the FreeBSD repository starting from its initial imports that led to FreeBSD 2.0, and
> - the current FreeBSD repository.
>
> The files appear to be added in the repository in chronological order
>   according to their modification time, and large parts of the source
>   code have been attributed to their actual authors. Commands like `git blame` and `git log` produce the expected results.

In particular, Figure 5 of the paper documents the proportional provenances of
the codebases comprising several Berkeley UNIX milestone releases.

I recommend his paper highly to anyone interested in the historical evolution
of UNIX and BSD.  The [GitHub page for the project](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo#project-status) is also interesting reading.

Comment: That does not prove in any way that FreeBSD is more similar to the original Unix than eg. NetBSD or a SysV derived system like Solaris. Also, the fact that is basically tracks a single branch makes it pretty useless for finding the origin and evolution of features like named pipes or /proc filesystem